# Is there a way to enforce method return types on Typescript classes via a tslint rule?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I've read the tslint rules [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules) and while it *looks* like [the typedef rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef)'s `call-signature` option is what I want, it doesn't complain about the lack of a return type.

Anyone know the rule (f one exists) to enforce return types on class methods?

Comment: Would `noImplicitAny` work better for you? IMO, I'd like to utilize the infer types as much as possible. :)

Comment: `noImplicitAny` is a compiler option, not a linting one, and will not guard against this case.  While I agree that inferred types are nice, there are situations where it's not clear what type of data is being returned from a method which is why we want to enforce it.

Comment: It seems that `call-signature` should work. Maybe you're also looking for `arrow-call-signature` as well?

Comment: @JKillian, I tried `arrow-call-signature` and that does WAY more than I'd bargained for, namely, it gripes at most of our arrow functions which don't declare return types - IIRC, the angular style guide indicates that they should not have return types, but I honestly don't remember.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Turns out this *can* be done via:

```
"typedef": [
  true,
  "call-signature",
  "property-declaration"
]
```

More info: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/

Comment: Just a note here that `"property-declaration"` is not necessary to accomplish OP's original goal; it is a discrete option to require interface property types.  `"call-signature"` is what matters here.

Comment: Oh cool.  Thanks for that clarification @runderworld.

Comment: note: tslint has been deprecated. https://palantir.github.io/tslint/ You can use https://typescript-eslint.io/ instead