# How to enforce a function to return a value of a given type?

Tags: typescript

Maybe there is a tsconfig option to set this, but if I write something like

```
function codeToMsg(a: number): string {
    if (a == 200)
        return "OK";
}

let msg = codeToMsg(123456);
```

I don't get an error from the compiler saying that the function may not return a value of the type string (it`s now returned undefined). How could this be enforced?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to enforce method return types on Typescript classes via a tslint rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793701/is-there-a-way-to-enforce-method-return-types-on-typescript-classes-via-a-tslint)

Comment: But I think it's not possible with the compiler

Comment: I'm talking about standard tsc config. tslint is another animal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn on either the `strictNullChecks` or `noImplicitReturns` compiler options to cause this to be an error

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `"noImplicitReturns": true`. This will issue a warning if not all code paths return a value.

Another option is to use `strictNullCheck`, which will cause your function to report an error, but that comes with a host of other behavior you probably don't want.