# Why do I need to declare the return type twice?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I am building an api just for practice.
In my solution I would like to provide some kind of cache functionality. Its type can be set in configuration file like writing into file or into database.

My question is rather related to the 'eslint', because during the development I am using typescript and I want to linting my source code before the commit.

I cannot understand the point of this warning message during the linting:

> 9:14  warning  Missing return type on function    @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type

I would like to avoid the duplication and use everything in the right place.

If I set again the return type like as at the check method then the message is gone. But in that case I cannot see the point to set it in the interface.

```js
interface CacheSolution {
  get(key: string): string;
  write(key: string, value: string): void;
  check(key: string): boolean;
}

class CacheIntoDatabase implements CacheSolution {

  public get (key) {
    return 'something';
  }

  public write (key: string, value: string) {

  }

  public check (key: string): boolean {
    return true;
  }

}
```

ESLINT configuration

```
module.exports = {
  'env': {
    'es6': true,
    'node': true
  },
  'extends': [
      'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'
  ],
  'globals': {
    'Atomics': 'readonly',
    'SharedArrayBuffer': 'readonly'
  },
  'parser':  '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  'parserOptions': {
    'ecmaVersion': 2018,
    'sourceType': 'module'
  },
  'rules': {
    'indent': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/indent': ['error', 2]
  }
};
```

Can I solve the warning somehow or I need to try live together with the duplication? :)

Comment: I would say that `public write` is the one that doesn't have the explicit `return`. Every function returns _something_ but if not explicitly written by you, you're likely to get that error.

Comment: `public get (key) {`
This one.   
Yes, you are right it has a return.  
But I have already declared the return type in the interface, so why do I need to set it again?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I'm guessing it has to do with how your ESLINT works. It's likely looking for the `return` keyword in every function you write since that's easier than checking the return type and 'skipping over' your `void` return. However an ESLINT warning won't break the code, it's simply a warning.

Comment: In general, you're saying *"Every implementation of `CacheSolution` **must** have a method `check` that returns a `boolean`."* If your implementation doesn't specify that its `check` method returns a `boolean`, then we cannot know if the interface has been completely/properly implemented. Your implementation could have a `check` method that returns a `string` instead, and this would be *wrong*. The duck typing of TypeScript might allow this but you would have an implementation that doesn't implement all methods of the interface.

Comment: Long story short, the purpose of an interface is not to *pass* information or definitions. Interfaces provide a strict set of instructions. If your interface says `check` returns a `boolean`, and your implementation doesn't say the same thing, then that implementation is _wrong_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

`public write (key: string, value: string) {`

to this

`public write (key: string, value: string):void {`

The reason you are getting this error probably has to do with you lint rules having a rule requiring method return types, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793701/is-there-a-way-to-enforce-method-return-types-on-typescript-classes-via-a-tslint) for more details on that.